# Change button:active in css

Tags: html, css

how i can change button to have border-radius: 6px; and to by active marked when i will select it. Here is my HTML code and i also have CSS. When i make `<button class:active`  i get only active button without css style

```html
<div align="center">
     <label>Period selection</label>
     <button class="button: active" id="Day" style="height:25px; width:60px; margin: 4px 2px" type="submit" onclick="setImage('1');">Day</button>
     <button class="button: active" id="Week" style="height:25px; width:60px; margin: 4px 2px" type="submit" onclick="setImage('2');">Week</button>
     <button class="button: active" id="Month" style="height:25px; width:60px; margin: 4px 2px" type="submit" onclick="setImage('3');">Month</button>
</div>
```

```css
.ctButton,
.button,
body div.ui-dialog div.ui-dialog-buttonpane div.ui-dialog-buttonset button.ui-button,
.ui-dialog .ui-button, 
a.button,
#ctPageContent a.button,
#ctPageContent a.button:hover {
     background-color: #2B2B2B;
     border: 0px;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 3px 10px 4px;
     color: #fff;
     text-decoration: none;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
     text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
     border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
     position: relative;
     cursor: pointer;
     margin: 4px 2px;
}
```

Comment: `:active` is a pseudo-class, not one that you can assign as a class to an element.

Comment: You don't seem to understand pseudo-selectors. `:active` can be used IN YOUR CSS to target currently active elements. Active elements are the one on which your are actually clicking (ex: a link on which you are currently clicking)...

Comment: As a side note, refrain from using the `align` attribute as it is depreciated.

Comment: I think you might need to learn some basic HTML/CSS first before you start coding. For some quick tutorials: HTML (http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) & CSS (http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp). For some premium tutorials, try http://teamtreehouse.com/

Comment: Also, it's best practice to place all your styles in a style sheet instead of placing them in the style attribute on the tag itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `:` indicates a [pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-classes) (pr pseudo-element). It is not part of the class name.

`:active` means "While being clicked on" (or otherwise activated).

If you want to match a class in the document, then give it a regular class name (and preferably not one that could be confused with a pseudo-class):

```
<button class="current"
```

Then use a class selector in the CSS:

```
.current { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css

```
.button:active{
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

In your html just add the below code.
NOTE- :active :hover should be in your css, not in your class attribute. Hence remove :active from your class attribute as below

```
<div align="center">
<label>
        Period selection   </label>
    <button class="button" id="Day" style="height:25px; width:60px; margin: 4px 2px" type="submit" onclick="setImage('1') ;">
        Day</button>

     <button class="button" id="Week" style="height:25px; width:60px; margin: 4px 2px" type="submit" onclick="setImage('2') ;">
        Week</button>

     <button class="button" id="Month" style="height:25px; width:60px; margin: 4px 2px" type="submit" onclick="setImage('3') ;">
        Month</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
class="button:active"
```

to

```
class="button"
```

and add to your css

```
button:active {
// your button:active styling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, colons have a special meaning: they introduce [pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-classes).

Therefore, if you want to select the following HTML by its class...

```html
<button class="button:active"></button>
```

...you must escape the colon:

```html
.button\:active
```

```css
.button\:active {
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  border: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 10px 4px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 4px 2px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button:active">Button</button>
```